# A Generic Pass-Through Interface. Is this possible?

Tags: c#, generics

What I wouldn't give to have this work:

```
public interface ICallBack
{
    void Handle<T>(T arg);
}

public class MessageHandler : ICallBack
{
    public void Handle<T>(T arg)
    {
        string name = typeof(T).Name;
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }

    public void Handle(int arg)
    {
        string name = "wow, an int";
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}

public class Worker
{
    public void DoSomething(ICallBack cb)
    {
        cb.Handle(55);
    }
}

//...
Worker foo = new Worker();
ICallBack boo = new MessageHandler();

//I want this to print "Wow, an int"
foo.DoSomething(boo)
```

Unfortunately, it calls the generic entry point rather than the "specialized" entry point.  Well, thats interfaces for you.

I've also tried the same approach but replacing the int-specific signature with a generic signature that is `Mojo` specific:

```
public void Handle<T>(T arg) where T : Mojo {}
```

I was hoping this would be sufficient to form a "special override" if the argument was of type `Mojo`.  But now the compiler complains that I have two methods with the same signature (one that is `Mojo` specific, the other open-ended).  Well, I was actually hoping it would think it was "the same signature" so that both would fulfill the interface and the "best" would be selected at run-time.  Ah well.

In effect, I'm trying to achieve is vaguely similar to "Traits," which are the "[else-if-then of C++](http://erdani.com/publications/traits.html)".  I guess it could also be considered a form of "interface signature contravariance."

I'd love to discover there is a special C# keyword that enables this capability, or that it is a featured addition to C# in .net 4.5.

Yes, no?  Comments?

Comment: Re: "Please upvote this question if you'd like to see this feature added to C#."  **This is not the purpose of upvoting on StackOverflow.** The purpose of upvoting here is to identify and encourage high quality questions. If you want to make a feature request for C#, use http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio.

Comment: Would it be impractical for you to work around this by checking the type in the generic method and putting the specialized behavior in that `if`? (Yes, I know it's ugly.)

Comment: You seem to want (partial) template specialization, which is something you can obtain rather easily with C++ templates (a compile-time model), but not easily with CLR generics (a mixed compiler/runtime model)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your `Worker` class to this:

```
public class Worker
{
    public void DoSomething(ICallBack cb)
    {
        ((dynamic)cb).Handle(55);
    }
}
```

[EDIT]

Just so you know, adding that innocuous-looking "dynamic" severely changes the output code. It effectively invokes the compiler at run-time to do the dynamic thing.

I also draw your attention to the comments and other answers here. I recommend you read them and understand why doing the above might not be such a great idea.

Further, as noted in the answer below, constraining the argument type to `ICallBack` **will still allow runtime errors** if the `Handle()` method is implemented explicitly.

Here's the IL for that simple-looking method:

```
.method public hidebysig instance void DoSomething(class ConsoleApplication1.ICallBack cb) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 9
    .locals init (
        [0] class [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo[] CS$0$0000)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldsfld class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Action`3<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, int32>> ConsoleApplication1.Worker/<DoSomething>o__SiteContainer0::<>p__Site1
    L_0006: brtrue L_0058
    L_000b: ldc.i4 256
    L_0010: ldstr "Handle"
    L_0015: ldnull 
    L_0016: ldtoken ConsoleApplication1.Worker
    L_001b: call class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
    L_0020: ldc.i4.2 
    L_0021: newarr [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo
    L_0026: stloc.0 
    L_0027: ldloc.0 
    L_0028: ldc.i4.0 
    L_0029: ldc.i4.0 
    L_002a: ldnull 
    L_002b: call class [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo::Create(valuetype [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfoFlags, string)
    L_0030: stelem.any [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo
    L_0035: ldloc.0 
    L_0036: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0037: ldc.i4.3 
    L_0038: ldnull 
    L_0039: call class [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo::Create(valuetype [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfoFlags, string)
    L_003e: stelem.any [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo
    L_0043: ldloc.0 
    L_0044: call class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder::InvokeMember(valuetype [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpBinderFlags, string, class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<class [mscorlib]System.Type>, class [mscorlib]System.Type, class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<class [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo>)
    L_0049: call class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<!0> [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Action`3<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, int32>>::Create(class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder)
    L_004e: stsfld class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Action`3<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, int32>> ConsoleApplication1.Worker/<DoSomething>o__SiteContainer0::<>p__Site1
    L_0053: br L_0058
    L_0058: ldsfld class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Action`3<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, int32>> ConsoleApplication1.Worker/<DoSomething>o__SiteContainer0::<>p__Site1
    L_005d: ldfld !0 [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Action`3<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, int32>>::Target
    L_0062: ldsfld class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Action`3<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, int32>> ConsoleApplication1.Worker/<DoSomething>o__SiteContainer0::<>p__Site1
    L_0067: ldarg.1 
    L_0068: ldc.i4.s 12
    L_006a: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.Action`3<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, object, int32>::Invoke(!0, !1, !2)
    L_006f: nop 
    L_0070: ret 
}
```

Comment: Why take ICallBack then?  Why not just take object?

Comment: @EricLippert Because `ICallback` has a `Handle()` method, so at least you won't get a runtime error if you pass a string or somesuch.

Comment: I haven't read the question but since you're expecting an `ICallback` parameter and are calling `Handle` on it, why do you need the cast to `dynamic`? Seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Tejas You should read the question then... If you don't cast it to `dynamic` it will say "Int32" and the OP specifically wanted it to say "wow, an int". In other words, he wants to do dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Casting it to `dynamic` bypasses the interface, you're no longer calling the method "through" the interface, you're calling any existing method on that object.

Comment: ah I see, yeah that makes sense. Sorry, like I said, i hadn't read the question and was confused about why a cast to dynamic would be required for a virtual method call. Just went over it.

Comment: Lasse is right; dynamic dispatch ignores interfaces because dynamic dispatch uses the *actual type* of the object, and an object is never actually *of* interface type.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I do know what you mean - but isn't it useful to use that interface to avoid runtime errors? In other words, I'm using the interface to constrain the argument type in a way that will avoid runtime errors, even though the `dynamic` itself doesn't use it. Or is that a bad thing to do for some reason?

Comment: I'm still new to dynamic dispatch.  Would this approach work if the interface were implemented explicitly?

Comment: @JeremyTodd No it doesn't (I just tried it) - I expect it deliberately won't call private methods.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I see what you are doing here.. you are using the interface to "take advantage" of the compiler type checking (so users of the API will not be allowed to pass something else), but inside you use dynamic to call the actual Handle implementation through dynamic dispatch.. clever, inefficient (as you pointed out in the edit) but clever!

Comment: @JeremyTodd If you implement the `Handle<T>` method explicitly in the class, and don't have any other "matching" Handle methods, then no, you will get a runtime error. Reflection (which is what `dynamic` will use in this case) will not use the method that implements the interface method explicitly. So if the goal is to avoid runtime errors, this will fail.

Comment: ... inefficient especially if you think that one of the reasons to have template specialization in C++ is to obtain better performances (see vector<bool>)

Answer (score 5):

No this is not possible.

When the compiler compiles the type implementing the interface, it will create an interface map detailing which methods of the type that is linked to each method of the interface. This cannot be changed at runtime at will.

This means that whenever you call your `Handle` method through that interface, it will always go to the same method on the underlying type, regardless of any other methods you feel should be more appropriate.

If you want the underlying type to call specific methods internally, depending on the specific type of the generic parameter, you will have to implement that yourself, either using dynamic dispatch, or by using if-statements or similar to detect which type of T you have and call the appropriate method.

The answer here that says you can cast the type you're calling the method on to `dynamic` means you're using reflection to bypass the interface alltogether. The interface might as well not have any methods at all for this particular scenario, the cast to `dynamic` will still "work".

I don't recommend this approach. You're effectively writing code that assumes it has carte blanche access to all methods of the underlying type, even though it specifically says "I only need this interface".

Additionally, if the only goal was to avoid runtime errors, consider what will happen if you implement the method explicitly in the class:

```
void Main()
{
    Worker foo = new Worker();
    ICallBack boo = new MessageHandler();

    foo.DoSomething(boo);
}

public interface ICallBack
{
    void Handle<T>(T arg);
}

public class MessageHandler : ICallBack
{
    void ICallBack.Handle<T>(T arg)
    {
        string name = typeof(T).Name;
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}

public class Worker
{
    public void DoSomething(ICallBack cb)
    {
        ((dynamic)cb).Handle(55);
    }
}
```

This will crash at runtime with:

> **RuntimeBinderException**:
>   'UserQuery.MessageHandler' does not contain a definition for 'Handle'

You can test the above code in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net).